# Where to update the Static Pages Blacklist for Multisite Install?

Tags: menus

***Where in the menu system is the link to this blacklist?***

As referenced in the codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration

> Also note that the blog prefix is not used for static pages which will
>   be accessible directly under the base address, e.g.
>   domain.com/PAGENAME. If you try to create a static page in the first
>   site with the name of another existing site on the network, the page's
>   permalink will get a suffix (e.g. domain.com/PAGENAME-2). If you
>   create a new site with the slug of an existing static page, the static
>   page will not be reachable anymore. To prevent this, you can ***add the
>   names of your static pages to the blacklist*** so that no site with that
>   name can be created.

After a few different searches I cannot find another reference to this static pages blacklist. I want to add a few pages like "contact,about,ect...". I have my wordpress setup and using multi-site.

Answer (score 1):

If you visit `/wp-admin/network/settings.php` you will get the `banned names` settings:

[image: Banned]